# Freeze/frost alarm for iOS

Tags: iphone, applications, software-recommendation, ios-appstore

I want to receive an alert whenever there is a freeze or frost advisory in my area, so I can know when to cover my plants. I would assume there is an app for that, but there are dozens weather apps, and all their features are not listed.

Ideally, I just need something like this Android app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cook.org&hl=en

Many apps offer weather alerts, but I don't want to get alerts for all inclement weather, just cold weather, and none made it clear that this is possible. Paid or free is fine. Thanks!

Comment: I use http://ifttt.com/ to send me an SMS the night before it's supposed to snow in my area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the [Weather Underground app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/weather-underground-radar/id486154808?mt=8). I use it a lot for weather information (for which it seems to have the most conclusive collection, and I also use it's excellent alerts.

One can choose any combination, from a complete list of warnings, which alerts to be notified of. You can also limit alerts to only notify you between certain times of the day.

I just confirmed, however, that it doesn't have an exclusive "Freeze Warning" alert that can be turned off and on. It has "Special Weather Statements", and "Winter Advisories", which would probably function that way. However, the "Winter Advisories" indicates that it is for accumulation type wintry precipitation.

It is a free app and very easy to configure those notifications. It has ads which can be disabled with a subscription, but those are irrelevant to push alerts.

Comment: +1 I set this up last year and forgot about it. I got alerts for our first freezes this year.

Answer (score 2):

One good option might be to combine [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) and [Pushover](https://pushover.net).

I currently get alerts whenever snow is forecast via this setup.

Comment: Great idea, and I didn't realize IFTTT had so many prewired data sources. +1

Comment: +1 I should have scrolled down to see this answer before I posted a comment about IFTTT on the question.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson you make a good point about SMS though; I use Pushover for a variety of reasons, but I forgot that SMS is another IFTTT channel.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread I know, but just found this in the Dark Sky app[image]

Comment: So sad that Apple bought and killed this app without integrating this custom alerts feature